# Android Animation Translation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

My android Translation would also translate to left hand side of the screen even though I have specified Y transition only.

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.6" android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:duration="1000" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-15%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Before image:
[image: Before image:]

After Image:
[image: After Image]

Comment: post the image before and after the animation (or better yet, a gif of the whole animation)

Comment: I have added the scrrenshots, please check !

Comment: i don't see any translation to the left. however, the scale animation uses the top-left corner as fixed point (pivot) by default. See pivot values at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#scale-element

Comment: Perfect ! I was missing the pivot point part, needs to get my basics right :)
Thank you.